# Volume over affine transformations across dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, volume, polytopes

My understanding is that, for an affine transformation with square matrix $T$, the volume of a set transformed through this affine transformation gets scaled by |det($T$)|.  However, if $T$ is rectangular, is there any analogous notion for calculating the volume of the transformed set, given the volume of the original set?

I realize the question may be a bit abstract, because the original and transformed sets are of different dimension when $T$ is rectangular.

Comment: Perhaps you want the square root of the Gram determinant?

Comment: Thanks Ted.  Following up, I now believe that what I asked for is not possible.
Thought experiment: mapping from an origin-centered cube (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) with side length 2 to an origin-centered square  (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) with side length 2. $T = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}$.  We'd get the same $T$ regardless of the $z$ height of the cube.  Because the transformation $T$ takes the $x,y$ components and throws out the $z$ component.  So, no function of $T$ alone can map from the volume of the rectangular prism to the volume of the square.

Comment: Ah, my suggestion only applies when $T\colon \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ with $n\le m$.